# Blank page after plugins (ACF pro) updates on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, error-handling, advanced-custom-fields

After I have updated some plugins in my wordpress site I have blank page and could not even login to my wp-admin. I have the ACF pro plugin and I think that someting is wrong with it, because I disabled manually another plugins and the problem still exists. Here you have the DEBUG LOGs.

```
[26-Oct-2017 06:47:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/header.php on line 16
.
.
.
[26-Oct-2017 06:51:10 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/header.php on line 16
[26-Oct-2017 06:51:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
.
.
.
[26-Oct-2017 07:09:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:14:00 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:16:04 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:16:36 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:16:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
.
.
.
[26-Oct-2017 07:16:52 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:18:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 118
[26-Oct-2017 07:19:08 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
.
.
.

[26-Oct-2017 07:20:55 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 141
[26-Oct-2017 07:21:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 118
[26-Oct-2017 07:21:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 118
[26-Oct-2017 07:24:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 142
[26-Oct-2017 07:27:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 142
[26-Oct-2017 07:27:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_field() in /home/virt6336/domains/mydomain.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/mydomain/functions.php on line 142
```

I have also the image with installed plugins:

[image]

I do not have any idea what I could do to solve my problem. Any of you had similar issue before ?

Comment: It looks like it is not loading the ACF plugin because it cant find the get_field() function.  Also it looks like you have a syntax error functions.php on line 141.  Have you changed the folder permissions for the plugin folders so the files don't load anymore?

Comment: I solved the syntax error, thanks. Folders permissions are 755 and the other files have 644. I have turned off also the ACF plugin right now, but still with result. Moreover I pasted the folder of the old version of ACF and It did not help...  Any ideas ?

Comment: Yes the problem is that you are referencing the ACF functions in your theme that's why it's getting a fatal error so it needs to be activated.  When you develop a theme/plugin it should check that the plugin is activated before it can be enabled otherwise you get yourself in this kind of situation.

Comment: Well... shlould I do something like this ([link](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/problem-with-function_exists-after-4-3-0-update/)) ? `is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php') == true` 

Thanks to you I know now, how to make it in the future, but can I do something with this current theme to make it work well ?

Comment: Yes that's what you need to incorporate into your theme.  I would incorporate the check so that you can't activate the theme unless the plugin is active.  This saves you from using that function is_plugin_active hundreds of times in your code.